# Enable plugin functions in plugin settings page

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I'm working on Wordpress plugin which have some functions. Now I have to create settings page for this plugin. On settings page I would enable and disable functions I made. I've tried to create HTML Form and add_action after submiting form. Example:

```
function add_links_to_admin_bar($admin_bar) {
//Whole function
}
if(isset($_POST["add_links"])){
  add_action( 'admin_bar_menu', 'pisz_add_links_to_admin_bar');
}
else if(isset($_POST["remove_links"])){
  remove_action( 'admin_bar_menu', 'pisz_add_links_to_admin_bar');
} else {
echo '<form action="" method="POST">
        <input type="submit" name="add_links" value="Add link to AB">
        <input type="submit" name="remove_links" value"Remove link AB">
      </form>';
```

Comment: Your function closes before you start your conditions.

Comment: Functions is not part of conditions
I want to call this functions with add_action using form